# New group ID when value changes from positive to negative using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Searched SO and surprised I couldn't find a solution, hopefully not a duplicate. And perhaps this is more a logic question rather than an R question per se, but hoping to find out:

1. why the outlined behaviours occur, and;
2. if my use of `ifelse()` with `cumsum()` is the problem, how to achieve the desired outcome in `dplyr` without using `ifelse()`, `cumsum()`, or both.

```
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
df <- data.frame(X = c(-10.9, -8.2, -6.3, -2.2, -0.3, 1.3, 4.6, -4.9, 3.6, 0, 1.8, 4.2, 9.8))
```

Desired output:

```
       X tile_x
1  -10.9      0
2   -8.2      0
3   -6.3      0
4   -2.2      0
5   -0.3      0
6    1.3      0
7    4.6      0
8   -4.9      1
9   -3.6      1
10   0.0      1
11   1.8      1
12   4.2      1
13   9.8      1
```

When I tried:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(tile_x = cumsum(ifelse(X < 0 & dplyr::lag(X, n = 1) > 0,
                                1, 0)))

df1
       X tile_x
1  -10.9     NA
2   -8.2     NA
3   -6.3     NA
4   -2.2     NA
5   -0.3     NA
6    1.3     NA
7    4.6     NA
8   -4.9     NA
9   -3.6     NA
10   0.0     NA
11   1.8     NA
12   4.2     NA
13   9.8     NA
```

The `ifelse()` without the `cumsum()` identifies the correct starting position for the group, but including `cumsum()` produces NAs.

I can achieve the desired output using:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(tile_x = cumsum(ifelse(X > 0 & dplyr::lead(X, n = 1) < 0,
                                1, 0)),
         tile_x = dplyr::lag(tile_x),
         tile_x = replace(tile_x, is.na(tile_x ), 0))
```

but this seems a bit untidy for `dplyr`. **NOTE** that the first value in tile_x does not have to be 0 if starting at 1 is easier to implement. The length of each group varies, but the pattern is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the first value of `lag()` output is `NA`, and this affects `cumsum()` results:

```r
c(1,2,3) |> cumsum()
#> [1] 1 3 6
c(1,2,3) |> dplyr::lag()
#> [1] NA  1  2
c(1,2,3) |> dplyr::lag() |> cumsum()
#> [1] NA NA NA
```

This can be fixed by setting the default value, i.e. `lag(..., default = 0)`:

```
c(1,2,3) |> dplyr::lag(default = 0) |> cumsum()
#> [1] 0 1 3
```

Also, there's no need to convert logical vector to numeric with `ifelse()`:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(X = c(-10.9, -8.2, -6.3, -2.2, -0.3, 1.3, 4.6, -4.9, 3.6, 0, 1.8, 4.2, 9.8))
df %>%
  mutate(tile_x = cumsum(X < 0 & lag(X, default = 0) > 0))
#>        X tile_x
#> 1  -10.9      0
#> 2   -8.2      0
#> 3   -6.3      0
#> 4   -2.2      0
#> 5   -0.3      0
#> 6    1.3      0
#> 7    4.6      0
#> 8   -4.9      1
#> 9    3.6      1
#> 10   0.0      1
#> 11   1.8      1
#> 12   4.2      1
#> 13   9.8      1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: In my environment, I have to be explicit with lag e.g. `dplyr::lag()`. Commenting in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hope `diff` for `sign(X)` makes sense to you

```
> df %>%
+   mutate(tile_x = cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(sign(X)) < 0)))
       X tile_x
1  -10.9      0
2   -8.2      0
3   -6.3      0
4   -2.2      0
5   -0.3      0
6    1.3      0
7    4.6      0
8   -4.9      1
9   -3.6      1
10   0.0      1
11   1.8      1
12   4.2      1
13   9.8      1
```

or `findInterval`

```
> df %>%
+   mutate(tile_x = findInterval(row_number(), 1 + which(diff(sign(X)) < 0)))
       X tile_x
1  -10.9      0
2   -8.2      0
3   -6.3      0
4   -2.2      0
5   -0.3      0
6    1.3      0
7    4.6      0
8   -4.9      1
9   -3.6      1
10   0.0      1
11   1.8      1
12   4.2      1
13   9.8      1
```